In Next.js must dynamic routes always rendered dynamically on the server?
I have a Next.js app (v14.1.2) which uses the app router.
One of my pages uses a dynamic route:
./src/app/c/[id]/page.tsx

This page

Is a client component with "use client";
Does not use any dynamic functions.
Does use {params} to get 'id' from the route but the value is only referenced inside a client-only useEffect(...) callback (all data-fetching is client-side).

As a result, the server should be able to send identical data to the client on each request because all data fetching is done in client components. However, I noticed in the output of next build that the page is rendered dynamically (even with export const dynamic = 'error';)
Route (app)                              Size     First Load JS
┌ ○ /                                    2.36 kB        97.4 kB
├ ○ /_not-found                          882 B          85.2 kB
├ λ /c/[id]                              3.03 kB          98 kB
...

○  (Static)   prerendered as static content
λ  (Dynamic)  server-rendered on demand using Node.js

It seems pretty wasteful to re-render static content on each request. When the payload will be the same on each render is it possible to opt in to static rendering of a dynamic route? What about static routes that use query parameters in client components?
Bonus points for references to the Next.js documentation that explain the intersection of static/dynamic rendering with static/dynamic routes.

generateStaticParams allows you to generate static routes at build time instead of request-time, you can read more about it here
